# Getting Status 504 using Rest Routing API

Tags: here-api

Since today other people and me are getting `504` Response / Timeout while using the Rest Routing API.

Yesterday everything worked fine. When I try to call the API via Browser I also get `504 Gateway Timeout`.
Other APIs are working as expected. It's only the Routing API which fails with `504`.

Requests are sent from Germany.

The status page shows that everything is up and running, but the Routing API is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

It started to work again as it should 3 minutes ago..
So I think the problem was solved by here.com ..